# How to resolve ORA 00936 Missing Expression Error?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-00936

```
Select /*+USE_HASH( a b ) */ to_char(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as LABEL,
ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 9, 16))) as VALUE,
from rrfh a, rrf b,
where ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 1, 9))) = 'stata kish' 
and a.xyz = b.xyz
```

The "from " (3rd line) part of the above query is giving me `ORA-00936 Missing EXPRESSION error`. Please Help me

**NOTE** :: rrfh table contains no data.

Comment: This error always means that Oracle is expecting another column and or table... it's usually caused by unneeded trailing commas as in your case or by unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: I had an extra comma in my query :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the comma?

```
select /*+USE_HASH( a b ) */ to_char(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as LABEL,
ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 9, 16))) as VALUE
from rrfh a, rrf b
where ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 1, 9))) = 'stata kish' 
and a.xyz = b.xyz
```

Have a look at [FROM](http://psoug.org/definition/FROM.htm)

> SELECTING from multiple tables You can include multiple tables in the
>   FROM clause by listing the tables **with a comma in between each table
>   name**

Comment: select /*+USE_HASH( a b ) */ to_char(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as LABEL,
ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 9, 16))) as VALUE,
from rrfh a, rrf b
where ltrim(rtrim(substr(oled, 1, 9))) = 'stata kish' 
and a.xyz = b.xyz

Comment: Also remove the comma after VALUE before from

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not the answer for the above mentioned question but it is related to same topic and might be useful for people searching for same error.

I faced the same error when I executed below mentioned query.

`select OR.* from ORDER_REL_STAT OR`

problem with above query was **OR** is keyword so it was expecting other values when I replaced with some other alias it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
update INC.PROV_CSP_DEMO_ADDR_TEMP pd 
set pd.practice_name = (
    select PRSQ_COMMENT FROM INC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA PRSQ
    WHERE PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_ITEM = 'PRNM' 
    AND PRSQ.PRAD_ID = pd.provider_id
    AND PRSQ.PRAD_TYPE = pd.prov_addr_type
    AND ROWNUM = 1
)
```

Answer (score -2):

This happens every time you **insert/ update and you don't use single quotes**. When the variable is empty it will result in that error. Fix it by using `''`

Assuming the first parameter is an empty variable here is a simple example:

Wrong

`nvl( ,0)`

Fix

`nvl('' ,0)`

Put your query into your database software and check it for that error. Generally this is an easy fix