# Excel VBA Run Time Error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I was handed a project at work, and when I run the macro, it comes up with this run time error:

[image]

When I go to debug the tool, it highlights this piece of code:

[image]

I looked at this [webpage](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/966146/run-time-error--2147217900-80040e14) for help and the workaround says to change settings in Enterprise, and I have no clue what that is.

My questions are:

1. What is Enterprise and is that the simple work around to this?
2. What is wrong with that portion of code to make it have this runtime error?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: This is caused by malformed SQL in the `query` variable, print it out and show what it is.

Comment: ORA-00936 looks like Oracle OLEDB Provider error to me.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156399/how-to-resolve-ora-00936-missing-expression-error   Please give the value of *query*.

Comment: Please verify the query that you passing, might have issues.

Comment: Either the query is malformed (see other comments) or cn is not an active connection for some reason.

Comment: @AlexK. It was referencing a database with a bad password, thanks!